# How to remove comments in all files including in subdirectories?

Tags: sed

to remove comments (start with `#` and `/* comment */`) in `settings.php`, below command is just works fine:

```
sed '/^\#/d' settings.php > outp.txt
mv outp.txt settings.php
sed '/\/\*/,/*\//d; /^\/\//d; /^$/d;' settings.php > outp2.txt
mv outp2.txt settings.php
sed '/^$/d' settings.php > outp3.txt
mv outp3.txt settings.php
```

But how to remove comments in all files including in subdirectories?

Comment: FYI, you can use `sed -i` to do an in-place edit. Also, you are doing `/^$/d` twice.

Comment: thanks. I'm newbie in using `sed`. I will look into it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from the directory you wish to traverse you can f.e. use `find ./ -type f -name '*.php' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '/^\#/d'`. xargs builds the argument list for sed for better performance and the -i option of sed replaces the pattern in-place (you don't have to use redirection).

**EDIT:** According to the manpage of *find* `find ./  -name '*.php' -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '/^\#/d'` is even faster, because it doesn't call *stat* on every file (-type option).

Comment: You might prefer to use the `-print0` parameter to `find` and use `xargs -0` - this will append \000 (chr(0), ascii character 0, 0x00, call it what you will) after each filename, and tells xargs to expect that character as a filename delimiter.  This allows you to cleanly handle filenames with spaces in them.

Answer (score 1):

You can sed 'in place' with -i. 
You can concat sed-commands with semicolons like this: 'c1;c2;c3' 
You can execute commands with find - no need for | xargs.

```
find ./somedir -name "*.php" -execdir sed -i '/^\#/d;/\/\*/,/*\//d; /^\/\//d; /^$/d;;/^$/d' {} +
```

This works for gnu-find on linux; maybe your find doesn't have -execdir, -exec should work as well, and maybe it doesn't have +, then ";" would be a simple but not that fast solution, or using xargs as shown above by p.vitzliputzli with the improvement from Matt for filenames with whitespace and special characters is an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
find -name '*.php' -exec ex -sc g/^#/d -cx {} ';'
```

1. `g` global search
2. `d` delete
3. `x` save and close